# Does the perception of time depend on the Mass/Height of the Observer?

Tags: mass, reference-frames, time, observers, perception

Okay. We were discussing the following thing at work. 
Situation: 
Imagine a high building. If it falls sideways, it takes a lot of time in our perception.

Now imagine something MUCH smaller. 
If we observe it, it will move very fast. Like a coin falling over.

Does an observer of a smaller size see the coin like we see the falling building? -> slower

If not (What i believe) can you tell me why?

Comment: Something high up takes longer to fall because the acceleration of gravity is the same in both cases and the large thing has farther to fall.

Answer (score 0):

To get this into a scale that is easy to visualize, let's say I am ten feet tall and you are 100 feet tall. In front of us are two sticks balanced so they are standing straight up. One is 10 feet tall and the other is 100 feet. We are looking at them and a gust of wind pushes them off balance and they begin to fall. As they fall we start to count together. We both see the ten foot stick fall flat first and at the same time. Then we both watch the 100 foot stick, still in its fall. It takes longer to fall because it has farther fall. We continue to count and we both see the tall stick fall flat at the same time.